# Collections sort

Tags: java, sorting, collections, vector

While sorting some data in a JTable I faced a problem when some German languages are present in the JTable.

I am giving a sample code that I tried out and the desired result that I require to work my application properly.

Code :

```
Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();

vec.add("ba~~~");
vec.add("ba~ab~~");
vec.add("ÇÊÕÝ");
vec.add("ÇÊÕÝ~ÂÉĒÐ~~");

System.out.println("Unsorted: "+vec);
Collections.sort(vec);
System.out.println("Sorted: "+vec);
```

**Output : 
Unsorted: [ba~~~, ba~ab~~, ÇÊÕÝ, ÇÊÕÝ~ÂÉĒÐ~~]

Sorted: [ba~ab~~, ba~~~, ÇÊÕÝ, ÇÊÕÝ~ÂÉĒÐ~~]**

**Output that I require:
Unsorted: [ba~~~, ba~ab~~, ÇÊÕÝ, ÇÊÕÝ~ÂÉĒÐ~~]

Sorted: [ba~ab~~, ba~~~, ÇÊÕÝ~ÂÉĒÐ~~, ÇÊÕÝ]**

From the output I see that the string 'ba~ab~~' comes before 'ba~~~' which is correct lexicographically. But I could not understand why 'ÇÊÕÝ~ÂÉĒÐ~~' comes after 'ÇÊÕÝ'. My requirement is to get the desired output (as I mentioned above) for my application to work correctly.

Am I missing anything that I need to provide while comparing special languages.

Any useful help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `ÇÊÕÝ~ÂÉĒÐ~~` comes after `ÇÊÕÝ` because `ÇÊÕÝ` is shorter. Lexicographically the prefixes goes first.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use the built-in collators (`Collator.getInstance(Locale.XXX)`)and implement `compareTo`, or if it is not a built-in collation, you will need to build your own using a `RuleBasedCollator` and then sort.  For details on the rule-based collatorsee:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423501/java-sort-a-collection-using-a-collatorkey

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Sir...@ Akber Choudhry...
   Ultimately I found that ~ (tilt) character is the main culprit. To compare these set If I use the extended ASCII character 'ÿ' with maximum ASCII value 255 it solves the problem like a charm.

I found the extended ASCII chars from http://www.ascii-code.com/